# Как отменить форматирование тега?

Tags: html, css

В html периодически встречаются теги со стандартным форматированием.
Например, `<p>`.
Есть ли в CSS какой-то атрибут, позволяющий разом убрать всё форматирование? всякие отступы и прочую ересь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НЕТУ.Можно менять поведение тегов вручную в CSS -файле.
Может можно создать самому такой атрибут ,прописав в js  поведение тега который имеет его.

Comment: понятно...жаль, что нету. спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Не изменяйте стиль определенного тега глобально, т.е. вот так

```
p {
    display: inline;
    color: #F00;
}
```

а создайте класс

```
.p_red_inline {
    display: inline;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Где стиль необходим - там подключаем класс, где нужно форматирование по умолчанию - просто класс не подключайте.

Answer (score -1):

Есть хорошее решение - cssreset.com – здесь собраны стили отменяющие стандартное форматирование популярных браузеров.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?